# How to get total issuance through polkadot.js.org/apps?

Tags: parachain, apps, constants

Not sure if I can add any more detail to the question!
How to get total issuance through polkadot.js.org/apps ?

It would also be helpful to know the general way to access chain constants through polkadot.js.org/apps.

Answer (score 5):

In polkadot{.js}'s Chain state > Storage > balances > totalIssuance

Like so:

[image: totalIssuance]

Comment: Bear in mind this is counted in the smallest unit so planks in the case of dot.

Comment: Yes take a look [here](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-DOT#polkadot) for conversion. So in this example, 11,835,195,980,139,420,511 Plancks would be 1,183,519,598.0139420511 Dots!